# Code window is stuck in odd configuration

Tags: visual-studio

My code window for my .cs files is stuck in this position, and I can't seem to see any of the text. The only workaround has been to use Window > Float, but this is not a great solution because I have to float every time I want to open a different .cs file.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing visual studio, but it is still stuck in this position.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: On the menu>>Window>>Reset Window Layout

Comment: This has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was caused by a corrupted solution and some corrupted files in my %appdata%\VisualStudio folder. I deleted the files and created a new solution to fix the issue.